# Software for working with Interactive response system

Tags: software-testing, reverse-engineering

I have a interactive response system pen (IRS pen) which looks like this:
[image: IRS PEN]

It usually works with interactive books. You have a interactive book full of symbols and when you aim this pen against certain symbol in a book, this IRS pen will read the certain text out loud for you.

#### Problem:

We have this pen and we would like to create a book for the IRC pen ourselves. The pen reads off of a special type of paper where behind every symbol there is some magnetic (or whatever) code. I would like to know what kind of technology is used within this pen or if there is any software which is compatible with this kind of technology. This pen works with .bnl files

The IRS pen and compatible book look like this,

[image: IRS Pen with IRS Pen compatible book]

Comment: To sum up. This interactive pen works with interactive books, as i said. We have this pen, but we dont know how to create this interactive books. This book have X texts and every text has a symbol next to its header. If you point a pen on this symbol, pen will play audio sound which belongs to that symbol. Basically we need a software which can create .bnl files ...